# How do i get my table's row information without an 'id'?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I've successfully been able to add new entries and update information using AppSync. However, I'm totally stumped when it comes to 'Get' information.

So for example if i try:

```
await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(getVideo, { id: ???? }))
```

I have no idea what my 'id' is. Obviously once the entry is created a unique id is created, but I have no way of knowing that unless going to my AWS console.

Or how can I get this id as a response when I create the entry?

I have created my own (as it were in dynamodb, SortKey) called 'myId' in creating the entry which I know. I need to use this 'myId' to retrieve the information in my table. How do I go about using this to get my table entry information?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you should still use the real `id` rather than the `myId` to get info about a newly created item.

You can easily get real `id` without needing to visit aws console by using `createVideo` graphql operation.

```
const createdVideo = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(mutations.createVideo));
const videoId = createdVideo.data.createVideo.id;
```

Also, `listVideos` graphql operation can list all ids.

```
const allVideos = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.listVideos));
const videoIds = allVideos.data.listVideos.items.map(video => video.id);
```

Comment: Thanks! I think using the 'id' is what i settled on after no avail. Worked. How do i store the listVideos in a localArray[ ]  ?

Comment: `const videos = allVideos.data.listVideos.items`

Comment: And for just the id's of that list of videos is it: const videos = allVideos.data.listVideos.items.id?

Comment: `const videos = allVideos.data.listVideos.items.map(v => v.id);`